# Test the connection to a network drive

Tags: python-3.x, shared-directory

I'm making an interface to connect network drives with python (and netuse). A tkinter button runs the connection command, and a textbox shows the connection state.
However, this textbox shows "connected" once the drive is visible in windows explorer, even if we cannot open it (due to a missing network). I have to click "disconnect" manually to make it appear as "disconnected" in my python program. (indeed, this disk isn't in the  win32net.NetUseEnum request anymore)

How can I do to test the disk connection before showing its status ?

Raphael

```
import os
import win32net
(_drives, total, resume) = win32net.NetUseEnum (None, 0, 0)
disques = []
for drive in _drives:
    if drive['local']== "V:":
        disques.append("v")
    if drive['local']=="U:":
        disques.append("u")

def monterU():
    if os.system(r"net use u: \\srsedc03\users") == 0:
        os.system(r"net use u: \\srsedc03\users")
        etatU.set("connecté")
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer somewhere else:
we can use the following code to check if every disk is reachable.

```
import os

for drive in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
    drive += ':'

try:
    os.scandir(drive)
    ok = "accessible"
except Exception:
    ok = "non accessible"

print(drive, os.access(drive, os.R_OK), ok)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from razorvla has an indentation error. Correct format should be

```
import os

for drive in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
    drive += ':'
    
    try:
        os.scandir(drive)
        ok = "accessible"
    except Exception:
        ok = "non accessible"
    
    print(drive, os.access(drive, os.R_OK), ok)
```

Besides the indentation, the answer worked on Python 3.6.

Comment: how is this answer different than the answer posted by the OP himself?